# Can't trigger autoscaling from availability test in Azure

Tags: azure, autoscaling

**Situation**

I have a simple availability test that just consists to call my home url every 5 minutes
This works fine.

I want to trigger autoscaling depending on the time this ping takes to respond.

**What I did**

So, for testing purpose, I completed the controller code by:

```cs
Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

Then in Monitor/Autoscale I created a rule for my service plan resource

I only build a scale out rule configured like:

- Resource type: availability test
- resource: my test name
- metric name: Response time
- time agregation: average
- duration: 5
- time grain: 5 minutes
- time grain statistic: average
- operator >=
- threshold: 1
- operation: increase count by
- increase count: 3
- cool down: 5

**My problem**

I am not sure about the unit of the theshold. But even if it is min it should trigger an autoscalling.
But I have never seen any scaling.

**My questions**

What might be wrong in my configuration?
I tested that autoscaling works fine if I monitor by number of request on my web site.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

**metric source**: other resource

**resource type**: application insights

**resource**: name of the instance of app insights owning the availability test

**metric namespace**: standard metric (preview)

**metric name**: availability test duration

Microsoft, you have a job to do on this form!